# Is there a difference between `nonvar(X)` and `\+var(X)`?

Tags: prolog

Prolog has the following to check current state of computation:

- `var/1`: [var(@Term)](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=var/1): "True if Term currently is a free variable."
- `nonvar/1`: [nonvar(@Term)](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nonvar/1): "True if Term currently is not a free variable."

Is there some difference between `nonvar(X)` and `\+var(X)`? Probably not?

**P.S.**

From the ISO standard:

> - `nonvar/1`: `nonvar(X)` is true iff `X` is not a member of the set `V` (7.1.1).  (p.69)
> - `var/1`   : `var(X)` is true iff X is a member of the `V` (7.1.1.). (p.67)

On page 27:

> **7.1.1. Variable**
>
> A variable is a member of a set V (see 6.1.2 a). While a goal is being executed, unification
>   may cause a variable to become unified with another term.

This should probably be rewritten slightly to bring in the idea of "X is the name of a currently fresh/unconstrained/unrefined variable".

Comment: Your question can be seen as being ambiguous. You are implying in practice (using a real Prolog like SWI-Prolog, or SICStus Prolog) but asking based the ISO standard. This assumes that every Prolog is ISO compliant and they are not.

Comment: @GuyCoder Ok, but would there be a reason to have nonvar(X) and \+var(X) differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference other than possibly on performance on a naive Prolog system (with `\+ var(X)` being slower than `nonvar(X)`).

Btw, with a clause such as:

```
a(X) :- \+ var(X).
```

The Logtalk linter reports:

```
*     Suspicious call: \+var(A) instead of nonvar(A)
```